# Criando um sistema de rotas

Tags: php, routing

Primeiramente boa tarde.

Estou tentando criar um sistema de rotas em PHP. Até o momento já tenho as seguintes rotas:

```
$prefix['teste'] = array('dados' => array(
                        'GET' => array(
                            'Auth/{id}' => array('Method' => 'ControllerAutenticacao@Auth', 'Logged' => 'true'),
                            'Outros/{id}' => array('Method' => 'ControllerAutenticacao@Auth', 'Logged' => 'true'),
                            'Outro/{id}' => array('Method' => 'ControllerAutenticacao@Auth', 'Logged' => 'true')),
                        'POST' => array(
                            'Auth/{id}' => array('Method' => 'ControllerAutenticacao@Auth', 'Logged' => 'true'))    
                        ));
```

minha duvida: como faço para que o PHP entenda que o que está dentro de chaves **/{id}** é um parâmetro?

Não sei se fui bem claro, é que prefiro entender a lógica antes de começar a usar frameworks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma mais simples é através de expressões regulares, você deve:

1. Alterar a string dentro das chaves para `([^/]*)` assim qualquer caracter diferente de `/` repetido 0 ou muitas vezes será capturado
2. Usar a função `preg_match` para comparar a rota criada (como uma expressão regular) e a rota da requisição, essa função retorna `1` caso a expressão regular combine com a rota da requisição e `0` caso contrário, verifique se o retorno é `1` para continuar
3. O terceiro parâmetro passado para a função anterior terá os valores das strings capturadas, crie um array associativo onde as chaves são as strings definidas entre chaves e os valores são a string correspondente na rota da requisição

Código

```
$rotaDaRequisicao = '/bar/1/teste';

$rotasCriadas = [
    '/foo',
    '/bar/{id}/{qualquerCoisa}'
];

// Parte 1
$rotasRegExp = preg_replace('#\{[a-z]+\}#i', '([^/]*)', $rotasCriadas);

foreach ($rotasRegExp as $index => $rota) {
    //Parte 2
    if (preg_match('#'.$rota.'#', $rotaDaRequisicao, $combinacoes) == 1) {
        array_shift($combinacoes);

        //Parte 3
        preg_match_all('#\{([a-z]+)\}#i', $rotasCriadas[$index], $chaves);

        $chaves = $chaves[1];

        $parametrosDaRota = array_combine($chaves, $combinacoes);

        //Aqui contém o array final, com o nome dos parâmetros definidos ao criar a rota e seus valores
        var_dump($parametrosDaRota);
    }
}
```

Se você só precisa dos valores de cada paramêtro, sem ser com as chaves como nome, pode pular a parte 3, o valor de `$combinacoes` vai ter um array numérico com os valores

Sugiro olhar o código fonte de alguns frameworks mais simples:

- [Alpha](https://github.com/Costamilam/Alpha)
- [Inphinit](https://github.com/inphinit/framework)
- [Klein.php](https://github.com/klein/klein.php)
- [FastRoute](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute)